# Changing label captions based on a combobox index?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

I have a userform with a combobox that is populated with a list of  client names that are stored in a hidden sheet. I am trying to make it so the user can select a name and click a button that brings up that client's profile (name address, phone number etc).

I am trying to get it to work for just the name before I do the other fields.  When I view the profile the name label (which I named `name_`) is blank.  `ClientBox` is the name of the combobox with the names which is on `userform2`, and `ClientProfile` is the name of the userform that has the name_ label.

The last 2 lines commented out are what I tried before I tried this method.  Neither method works.

```
Sub ProfilePopulator()
    Dim index As Integer, str As String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Clients").Visible = True
    Sheets("Clients").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    index = UserForm2.ClientBox.ListIndex
    str = Cells(index + 1, 1)
    ClientProfile.Name_.Caption = str
    'ActiveCell.Offset(index, 0).Select
    'ClientProfile.Name_.Caption = ActiveCell
End Sub
```

Comment: `Neither one is working`. Please explain what is not working?

Comment: Right. More specifically... is there an error message? Does str get assigned the value you expect? At what point does it fail to work?

Comment: str was assigned to the name,  so clientprofile.name_.caption = str is not working I think

Comment: I meant the method setting name_ equal to str nor the method setting name_ equal to ActiveCell worked.

Comment: Where is this `Sub ProfilePopulator()`? In a module or one of the forms code? Have you tried `ClientProfile.Name_.Caption = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Clients").Cells(index + 1, 1).Value`?

Comment: ProfilePopulator is in a module. I will give that a try thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't actually in this part of the code (oops).  It was in the code for the button that opens the ClientProfile userform.  Before I had:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
UserForm2.Hide
ClientProfile.Show
Call ProfilePopulator
End Sub
```

ProfilePopulator has to run *before* ClientProfile is shown, so now it looks like this and it works:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
UserForm2.Hide
Call ProfilePopulator
ClientProfile.Show
End Sub
```